# How to dynamically load a Python class

Tags: python, reflection, python-import

Given a string of a Python class, e.g. `my_package.my_module.MyClass`, what is the best possible way to load it?

In other words I am looking for a equivalent `Class.forName()` in Java, function in Python. It needs to work on Google App Engine.

Preferably this would be a function that accepts the FQN of the class as a string, and returns a reference to the class:

```
my_class = load_class('my_package.my_module.MyClass')
my_instance = my_class()
```

Comment: I need to be able to assign the class reference to a variable as well.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname

Comment: You are right it is a duplicate, thanks for finding it

Comment: @JohnTyree How does loading classes dynamically mean a program isn't interesting? Can you give an example so that this criticism can be more useful to SO members?

Comment: Interesting "enough." It's just a tongue-in-cheek way of saying that doing weird things is sometimes necessary because of factors that you can't control and are hard to predict. The previous comment basically said, "Why don't you just import the normal way?" and I'm saying that they too will someday have a weird corner case that requires doing something ugly.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

From the python documentation, here's the function you want:

```
def my_import(name):
    components = name.split('.')
    mod = __import__(components[0])
    for comp in components[1:]:
        mod = getattr(mod, comp)
    return mod
```

The reason a simple `__import__` won't work is because any import of anything past the first dot in a package string is an attribute of the module you're importing.  Thus, something like this won't work:

```
__import__('foo.bar.baz.qux')
```

You'd have to call the above function like so:

```
my_import('foo.bar.baz.qux')
```

Or in the case of your example:

```
klass = my_import('my_package.my_module.my_class')
some_object = klass()
```

**EDIT**:  I was a bit off on this.  What you're basically wanting to do is this:

```
from my_package.my_module import my_class
```

The above function is only necessary if you have a *empty* fromlist.  Thus, the appropriate call would be like this:

```
mod = __import__('my_package.my_module', fromlist=['my_class'])
klass = getattr(mod, 'my_class')
```

Comment: I tried my_import('my_package.my_module.my_class') but get no module found my_class, which makes sense since it is a class not a module.

Howver if I can use gettattr to get the class after the call to my_import

Comment: That's odd.  Everything past the first dot is called using getattr.  There shouldn't be any difference.

Comment: Thanks I think this is the best way. Now I only need the best way to split the string 'my_pakcage.my_module.my_class' into mod_name, klass_name but I guess I can figure that out :)

Comment: The `my_import()` code is not needed, as you can use dots in an `__import__()` call just fine. They all have to refer to module names however. A symbol from the module needs to be fetched with `getattr()`.

Comment: If you use mod = __import__(name.split('.')[0]) and then components=name.split('.')[1:] (or equivalent) it works also for classnames. E.g. my_import("datetime.date")

Comment: Your edit solution works without the `fromlist` option (in python 2) i.e.
`mod = __import__('my_package.my_module');`
`klass = getattr(mod, 'my_class')`
is fine. I can't for the life of me work out the effect of `fromlist`, [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) is not clear to me.

Comment: python documentation (on the code) of __import__ says to use importlib. so should checkout answer by Adam Spence

Comment: Link @naoko is referring to: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.__import__

Answer (score 195):

```
import importlib

module = importlib.import_module('my_package.my_module')
my_class = getattr(module, 'MyClass')
my_instance = my_class()
```

Comment: once you've imported the module dynamically you have access to the class via the module

Comment: Great! It's even part of standard library from 2.7 and up.

Comment: This is the correct way to access a module / class. The docs state this here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.__import__

Answer (score 186):

If you don't want to roll your own, there is a function available in the `pydoc` module that does exactly this:

```
from pydoc import locate
my_class = locate('my_package.my_module.MyClass')
```

The advantage of this approach over the others listed here is that `locate` will find *any* python object at the provided dotted path, not just an object directly within a module.  e.g. `my_package.my_module.MyClass.attr`.

If you're curious what their recipe is, here's the function:

```
def locate(path, forceload=0):
    """Locate an object by name or dotted path, importing as necessary."""
    parts = [part for part in split(path, '.') if part]
    module, n = None, 0
    while n < len(parts):
        nextmodule = safeimport(join(parts[:n+1], '.'), forceload)
        if nextmodule: module, n = nextmodule, n + 1
        else: break
    if module:
        object = module
    else:
        object = __builtin__
    for part in parts[n:]:
        try:
            object = getattr(object, part)
        except AttributeError:
            return None
    return object
```

It relies on `pydoc.safeimport` function.  Here are the docs for that:

```
"""Import a module; handle errors; return None if the module isn't found.

If the module *is* found but an exception occurs, it's wrapped in an
ErrorDuringImport exception and reraised.  Unlike __import__, if a
package path is specified, the module at the end of the path is returned,
not the package at the beginning.  If the optional 'forceload' argument
is 1, we reload the module from disk (unless it's a dynamic extension)."""
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer. BTW, here is the code that also have safeimport as it seems odd to import pydoc just for this: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/aa8ea3a6be22c92e774df90c6a6ee697915ca8ec/Lib/pydoc.py#L288

Comment: I upvoted this answer too, this is the best of all relevant answers.

Comment: This seems to be able to handle ``qualname`` (object not at top of module namespace) correctly as well.

Comment: yes, you can do `locate('my_package.my_module.MyClass.attr.method.etc')`

Comment: actually the best answer

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but it seems like this should be in a different package than in `pydoc`.

Comment: Upvoted. But it is odd that this function is in module `pydoc` and still un-documented.

Answer (score 54):

If you're using Django you can use [`import_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.module_loading.import_string).

*Yes i'm aware OP did not ask for django, but i ran across this question looking for a Django solution, didn't find one, and put it here for the next boy/gal that looks for it.*

```py
# It's available for v1.7+
# https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/utils/module_loading.py
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string

Klass = import_string('path.to.module.Klass')
func = import_string('path.to.module.func')
var = import_string('path.to.module.var')
```

Keep in mind, if you want to import something that doesn't have a `.`, like `re` or `argparse` use:

```py
re = __import__('re')
```

Answer (score 30):

```
def import_class(cl):
    d = cl.rfind(".")
    classname = cl[d+1:len(cl)]
    m = __import__(cl[0:d], globals(), locals(), [classname])
    return getattr(m, classname)
```

Comment: This is the clean solution! You could consider using: `(modulename, classname) = cl.rsplit('.', 2)`

Comment: It's great) I had created putils package with different utils, also class importing there. If you want, you can use it from that package.

Comment: @vdboor `rsplit('.', 1)` ?

Comment: I managed to pass {} instead of globals/locals and it still works fine

Answer (score 19):

Here is to share something I found on `__import__` and `importlib` while trying to solve this problem.

I am using Python 3.7.3.

When I try to get to the class `d` in module `a.b.c`,

```
mod = __import__('a.b.c')
```

The `mod` variable refer to the top namespace `a`.

So to get to the class `d`, I need to

```
mod = getattr(mod, 'b') #mod is now module b
mod = getattr(mod, 'c') #mod is now module c
mod = getattr(mod, 'd') #mod is now class d
```

If we try to do

```
mod = __import__('a.b.c')
d = getattr(mod, 'd')
```

we are actually trying to look for `a.d`.

When using `importlib`, I suppose the library has done the recursive `getattr` for us. So, when we use `importlib.import_module`, we actually get a handle on the deepest module.

```
mod = importlib.import_module('a.b.c') #mod is module c
d = getattr(mod, 'd') #this is a.b.c.d
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_import(name):
    components = name.split('.')
    mod = __import__(".".join(components[:-1]))
    for comp in components[1:]:
        mod = getattr(mod, comp)
    return mod
```

Fix error import on python 3.11

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

OK, for me that is the way it worked (I am using Python 2.7):

```
a = __import__('file_to_import', globals(), locals(), ['*'], -1)
b = a.MyClass()
```

Then, b is an instance of class 'MyClass'

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to already have an instance of your desired class, you can use the 'type' function to extract its class type and use this to construct a new instance:

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def display(self):
        print(self.name)

one = Something("one")
one.display()
cls = type(one)
two = cls("two")
two.display()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python has an inbuilt library importlib to get the job done. :**, How to access module method and class method dynamically bypassing package name as a param. An example is given below.

**Module 1:**

```
def get_scenario_data():
    return "module1 scenario data"


class Module1:

    def module1_function1(self):
        return "module1_function"

    def module1_function2(self):
        return "module2_function"
```

**Module 2:**

```
def get_scenario_data():
    return "module2 scenario data"



class Module2:

    def module2_function1(self):
        return "module2_function1"

    def module2_function2(self):
        return "module2_function2"
```

ModuleTest:

1. Will access the module methods dynamically based on the package name as param
2. Will access the class methods dynamically based on the package name as param.

**ModuleTest**

```
import importlib

module = importlib.import_module('pack1.nestedpack1.module1')
print(module.get_scenario_data())
modul1_cls_obj = getattr(module, 'Module1')()
print(modul1_cls_obj.module1_function1())
print(modul1_cls_obj.module1_function2())

module = importlib.import_module('pack1.nestedpack1.module2')
modul2_cls_obj = getattr(module, 'Module2')()
print(modul2_cls_obj.module2_function1())
print(modul2_cls_obj.module2_function2())
print(module.get_scenario_data())
```

**Results**

```
module1 scenario data
module1_function
module2_function
module2_function1
module2_function2
module2 scenario data
```

Answer (score 0):

## PyPI module autoloader & import

```py
# PyPI imports
import pkg_resources, subprocess, sys

modules   = {'lxml.etree', 'pandas', 'screeninfo'}
required  = {m.split('.')[0] for m in modules}
installed = {pkg.key for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set}
missing   = required - installed

if missing:
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pip'])
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', *missing])

for module in set.union(required, modules):
    globals()[module] = __import__(module)
```

Tests:

```py
print(pandas.__version__)
print(lxml.etree.LXML_VERSION)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit of sophistication to the existing answers....

Depending on the use case, it may be somewhat inconvenient to have to explicitly specify the full path (E.g. `package.subpackage.module...`) of the class/method you want to import. On top of importlib, we can leverage `__init__.py` to make things even cleaner.

Let's say I have a python package, like so:

```
├── modes
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── bar.py
│   ├── foo.py
│   ├── modes.py
```

`foo.py`, say, have some class/functions we'd like to use somewhere else in our program:

```
from modes.modes import Mode

class Foo(Mode):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*arg, **kwargs)
        
    def run(self):
        self.LOG.info(f"This is FOO!")
```

With a command line argument, I can pass an argument that corresponds to a mode that I want to run. I'd like to be able to so something like this:

```
def set_mode(mode):
    """  """
    import importlib
    module = importlib.import_module('modes.foo')
    getattr(module, mode)().run()
```

which outputs:

```
>> set_mode("Foo")
>> engine_logger:INFO - This is FOO!
```

That works fine, however what we'd REALLY want to get at is this:

```
def set_mode(mode):
    """  """
    import importlib
    module = importlib.import_module('modes')  # only import the package, not modules explicitely
    getattr(module, mode)().run()
```

Which raises an error:

```
>> set_mode("Foo")
>> AttributeError: module 'modes' has no attribute 'Foo'
```

However, we can add the following to `/modes/__init__.py`:

```
from .foo import Foo
from .bar import Bar
```

Then, we can do:

```
>> set_mode("Foo")
>> engine_logger:INFO - This is FOO!

>> set_mode("Bar")
>> engine_logger:INFO - This is BAR!
```

In other worlds, all sub modules/functions/classes we import in init.py will be found directly with importlib.import_module(...), without having to specify the full path from outside.

Answer (score 0):

I have created this method

```
import importlib
import sys
import os


def import_classes(root_directory: str):
    imported_classes, import_errors = [], []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_directory):

    if os.path.isabs(root):
        """
            When an absolute path is specified: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\PycharmProjects\\my_project\\_dev\\plugin_discovery\\scenarios'
            we will add the parent directory: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\PycharmProjects\\my_project\\_dev\\plugin_discovery' into "sys.path" variable
            and we will start to create the import path starting from the last parent directory: "scenarios"
        """
        parent_dir, last_parent_directory = os.path.dirname(root), os.path.basename(root)

    else:
        # When a relative path is specified; just add the current working directory into "sys.path" variable
        parent_dir, last_parent_directory = os.getcwd(), root

    """
    Python searches for modules starting from each path specified in "sys.path" list.
        Example:
            Current working directory: "C:\\Users\\admin\\PycharmProjects\\my_project\\_dev\\plugin_discovery"
            last_parent_directory:  "scenarios"

            If current working directory in sys.path, python will try to import the module from:
                "C:\\Users\\admin\\PycharmProjects\\my_project\\_dev\\plugin_discovery\\scenarios"
    
    This is why we add the parent directory into "sys.path" variable
    """
    if parent_dir not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir)

    # Import classes from Python Files
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            module_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]  # Remove the file extension to get the module name
            last_parent_directory = last_parent_directory.replace("..\\", "").replace("../", "").replace(".\\", "").replace("./", "")  # Remove relative path prefix
            last_parent_directory = last_parent_directory.replace("\\", ".").replace("/", ".")  # Replace path separators with dots

            module_import_path = f"{last_parent_directory}.{module_name}"  # Build module import path

            try:
                # Force the module to be reimported if it has already been imported
                if module_import_path in sys.modules:
                    del sys.modules[module_import_path]
                
                module_object = importlib.import_module(module_import_path)
                
                # Iterate over items in the module_object
                for attribute_name in dir(module_object):
                    # Get the attributes from the module_object
                    attribute = getattr(module_object, attribute_name)

                    # Check if it's a class and append to list
                    if isinstance(attribute, type):
                        imported_classes.append(attribute)

            except Exception as import_error:
                # In case of import errors; save the import arguments and the error and continue with other files
                import_errors.append((parent_dir, module_import_path, import_error))

return imported_classes, import_errors
```

Now, lets suppose we have the following folder structure and classes:

```
scenarios_root (directory)
  scenarios (directory)
    scenario1.py
      -> Scenario1 (class)
      -> Scenario2 (class)
      -> Scenario3 (class)
                
    scenario2.py
      -> ScenarioA (class)
      -> ScenarioB (class)
      -> ScenarioC (class)
```

If we execute the import function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  imported_clas, import_err = import_classes(r"..\_dev\2023_08_30_plugin_discovery\scenarios_root")
  print(f"Number of imported classes: {len(imported_clas)}")
  print(f"Imported classes: {imported_clas}")
  print(f"Import errors: {import_err}", end="\n\n")
```

Output:

```
Number of imported classes: 6
Imported classes: [<class '_dev.2023_08_30_plugin_discovery.scenarios_root.scenarios.scenario1.Scenario1'>, <class '_dev.2023_08_30_plugin_discovery.scenarios_root.scenarios.scenario1.Scenario2'>, <class '_dev.2023_08_30_plugin_discovery.scenarios_root.scenarios.scenario1.Scenario3'>, <class '_dev.2023_08_30_plugin_discovery.scenarios_root.scenarios.scenario2.ScenarioA'>, <class '_dev.2023_08_30_plugin_discovery.scenarios_root.scenarios.scenario2.ScenarioB'>, <class '_dev.2023_08_30_plugin_discovery.scenarios_root.scenarios.scenario2.ScenarioC'>]
Import errors: []
```

Answer (score 0):

One can try this:

```
from pydoc import locate

module = locate("path to py file"))
if module != None:
  classname = getattr(module, "class name")
  if classname != None:
       classobject = classname("arguments")
```

Answer (score -1):

In Google App Engine there is a `webapp2` function called `import_string`. For more info see here:https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html

So,

```
import webapp2
my_class = webapp2.import_string('my_package.my_module.MyClass')
```

For example this is used in the `webapp2.Route` where you can either use a handler or a string.

Answer (score -2):

```
module = __import__("my_package/my_module")
the_class = getattr(module, "MyClass")
obj = the_class()
```

Comment: Note that this works because of a bug in the __import__ function. File paths should *not* be used in the __import__ function and will not work in python 2.6 and above: http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#porting-to-python-2-6