# How to transform tuple of string(object locations) to dictionary of objects in python

Tags: python

I would like to transform a tuple:

```
TEST_CLASSES = (
   'common.test.TestClass',
)
```

to

```
TEST_CLASSES = {
   'test': common.test.TestClass,
}
```

How to make a dictionary is simple but I have a problem with conversion from string to object. Could anybody help me please? thanks!

Comment: i think this is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname

Comment: As far as I understand, you try to get class by its string name. There were similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547829/how-to-dynamically-load-a-python-class, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval), which can be **evil** if your inputs are not safe:

```
>>> import os
>>> eval('os.path.join')
<function join at 0x00BBA2B8>
```

if the `common.test.TestClass` doesn't exist in the current namespace a `NameError` will be raised:

```
>>> eval('math.isnan')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    eval('math.isnan')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you try to get class by its string name. There was a similar question: [How to dynamically load a Python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547829/how-to-dynamically-load-a-python-class)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly "convert from string to object" (though in a technical sense, strings are objects), but you can use a function that can import the objects for you. Werkzeug's `werkzeug.utils` module has a function in it named `import_string` that does just that ([source here](http://bitbucket.org/mitsuhiko/werkzeug-main/src/tip/werkzeug/utils.py#cl-498)).

(I'm assuming that the objects you want are to be imported from modules.)

So, if you use a similar `import_string` function, you can transform the tuple to a dictionary with this:

```
test_classes = {}
for path in TEST_CLASSES:
    obj = import_string(path)
    test_classes[obj.__module__.split('.')[-1]] = obj
```

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward and oftenly not recomended way there is to use "eval".

Simply doing:

```
obj = eval('common.test.TestClass')
```

Will give you the object as specified on the string.

Other, more elegant ways, would involve querying each object on the chain for the next attribute - you can avoud eval in this way:

```
string = 'common.test.TestClass'

# this retrieves the topmost name, supposedly a module, as an object:
obj = globals()[string.split(".")[0]]

# And retrieve each subobject object therein:
for part in string.split(".")[1:]:     
    obj = getattr(obj, part)
```

If part of your object path is an yet not-imported submodule, though, this won't work - You'd have to "exec" an import statement to retrieve the module - Exec being a "stronger" form of eval, wich supports statements, while eval is reserved only for expressions.