# How may I resolve python path strings with Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm currently writing a Django template template tag, and I would like to be able to reference a class in it with a string, just like in `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, for example. The tag would look like `{% mytag "myproject.lib.mymodule.SomeClass" %}`.

The question is fairly simple : in my template tag, how may I easily resolve this string to the actual referenced class?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is "yes".  Now.  Please edit the question to ask what you **really** what to know, which is "how do I transform a class name  into a class object."  Then we can ask "Why are you trying to do this?"  Often, you'd be happier with some other technique.  Please explain what your tag will do with the class object named as an argument.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing how this is done, regardless of whether it's the best way of doing things or not

Comment: Thanks. The question was purely technical, and could be useful in many places, not necessarily in a template tag. But if you are curious, the goal is to create something similar to [Facebook's BigPipe](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/bigpipe-pipelining-web-pages-for-high-performance/389414033919). The tag will take a Pagelet class path as argument, register it for deferred rendering, and finally return the placeholder, if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to import a package specified as a string, you will need to check out the [`__import__` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__).

Basic usage is that you can attempt to import the package specified in the string like

```
my_class = __import__("myproject.lib.mymodule.SomeClass")
```

which is equivalent to

```
import myproject.lib.mymodule.SomeClass as my_class
```

However, as S.Lott mentioned, you'll need to consider carefully if that's really the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks ! I considered many other options, but this one really seems to be the most flexible.

Comment: Just to add that the solution doesn't actually work as is, and I needed a little rsplit magic, and the `fromlist` argument of the `__import__` function. I actually read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547829/how-to-dynamically-load-a-python-class) to find the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Django has some utility functions for handling this situation.

In Django 1.7 or higher, use [`django.utils.module_loading.import_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.module_loading.import_string) function.

In Django 1.6, use [`django.utils.module_loading.import_by_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/utils/#django.utils.module_loading.import_by_path) function.

(It looks like `import_by_path` exists in 1.5 as well, although it's not documented)

Example usage:

```
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string

my_class = import_string('myproject.lib.mymodule.SomeClass')
```