# Can not import class from another path - ValueError: Empty module name

Tags: python, import

I followed advice here on stackoverflow on how to import a class
from a path outside of the root folder:
[How to dynamically load a Python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547829/how-to-dynamically-load-a-python-class)
[Does python have an equivalent to Java Class.forName()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname)

Unfortunately this raises the error: 
**ValueError: Empty module name**

It is my understanding that import should not return an empty module, like the load_source method from imp. So I do not understand this error nor how to approach it.

**What am I implementing wrong here?
Could you tilt me into the right direction here?**

Thanks!

Code:

```
klass = __import__('..folder.module.Class_A')
some_object = klass()

class class_B(some_object):
    def run(self):
        print ('Test OK!')
```

Imported class (content of module):

```
class Class_A():
    def __init__(self, arg1, *args):
def run(self):
    pass
```

Comment: "__import__('..folder.module.Class_A')" is *not* what is suggested in your link. I suggest you reread it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you are not using import correctly.

**Option 1**:

According to  [https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#**import**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) you should be doing:

```
klass = __import__('folder.module', globals(), locals(), ['Class_A'], -1)
```

Now if you want Class_A itself you should do:

```
some_object = klass.Class_A
```

Then you can inherit from it using:

```
class class_B(some_object):
    def run(self):
        print ('Test OK!')
```

**Option 2**:

```
from folder.module import Class_A
```

Then you can inherit from it using:

```
class class_B(Class_A):
    def run(self):
        print ('Test OK!')
```

**Note**: In folder.module folder should be a python package and module should be a python module

Comment: Downvoting and not making a comment is very not helpful!