# How to make abstract Python class from string?

Tags: python, class, abstract

I'm working on module which saved users' data onto Parse.com cloud.
Using [Parse.py](https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy) library, I need to do this:

```
class Cat:
    pass
cat = Cat()
cat.name = 'Alice'
cat.save()
```

Where `Cat` is name of table in cloud.
Is it possible somehow to create class dynamically from string not having it anywhere else before?
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821104/python-dynamic-instantiation-from-string-name-of-a-class-in-dynamically-imported) is suggested, that there's module with pre-defined class.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176136/convert-string-to-python-class-object) `eval` is also used on pre-defined class.

So, it it possible to create class dynamicallly in runtime only from string? Something like:

```
save_data('Alice','myclass')

def upload(cat_name, class_name):
    class_name.name = cat_name
    class_name.save()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I dynamically create derived classes from a base class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247075/how-can-i-dynamically-create-derived-classes-from-a-base-class)

Comment: Looks more like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547829/how-to-dynamically-load-a-python-class OP is trying to load a class, not create a new one.

Comment: I mean Abstract class, not class with pre-defined arguments  And I'm not trying to import it, I'm creating new in runtime

Comment: @Kondra007 What exactly do you mean by an abstract class? A class that cannot be instantiated?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I mean: `class Foo: pass` where (in my case) `Foo`  is given as string in runtime