# Where to Start with Custom Reporting Python/Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, report

I'm trying to find a way to build a robust report library that I can use with a Django project.

Essentially, what I'm looking for is a way to access a list of functions(reports) that I can allow an end-user to attach to a Django model.

For example, let's say I have an Employee object. Well, I have a module called  reports.py that has a growing list of possible reports that take an employee object and output a report, usually in JSON form. There might be number of timecards submitted, number of supervisions created, etc.

I want to be able to link those changing report lists to the Employee object via a FK called (job description), so admins can create custom reports per job description.

What I've tried:

- Direct model methods: good for some things, but it requires a programmer to call them in a template or via API to generate some output. Since the available reports are changing, I don't want to hard-code anything and would rather allow the end-user to choose from a list of available reports and attach them to a related model (say a JobDescription).
- dir(reports): I could offer up a form where the select values are the results from dir(reports), but then I'd get the names of variables/libraries called in the file, not just a list of available reports

Am I missing something? Is there a way to create a custom class from which I can call all methods available? Where would I even start with that type of architecture?

I really appreciate any sort of input re: the path to take. Really just a 'look in this direction' response would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is expand on your `dir(reports)` idea and create a dynamically loaded module system. Have a folder with .py files containing module classes. [Here's an example of how you can dynamically load classes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547829/how-to-dynamically-load-a-python-class).

Each class would have a static function called `getReportName()` so you could show something readable to the user, and a member function `createReport(self, myModel)` which gets the model and does it's magic on it.

And then just show all the possible reports to the user, user selects one and you run the `createReport` on the selected class.

In the future you might think about having different report folders for different models, and this too should be possible by reflection using model's `__name__` attribute.

Comment: So in that example, would each report be a standalone class?

Comment: @Craig Yes, a small one, but it would allow you a lot more flexibillity in the future in case you would want to add a report description or anything additional