# Dynamically importing a class from a path which is not contained in a module

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, python-import

I am trying to use python files containing classes as some sort of config file. Thus i have multiple paths which lead to config.py files. I than want to load these files and thus gain access to the classes and the containing data.
Is there a module which enables me to access the class in a given file, for example like this:

```
def get_config(path):
    # path = "....\config.py"     #containing a class <Options>
    file = load_class(path)     
    return file.Options
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547829/how-to-dynamically-load-a-python-class