# Import a module from a pathlib source file path

Tags: python, pathlib, python-importlib

I have:

```
from pathlib import Path
if some_condition:
    path1 = Path(r'path/to/file.py')
else:
    path1 = Path(r'path/to/other_file.py')
```

And I want to dynamically import class `class1` from that path (both `file.py` and `other_file.py` have a class named `class1`). How can I do that?

**UPDATE:**

I managed to get the module object successfully:

```
import importlib.util

file_name = path1.name

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(file_name, path1)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
```

But I still don't know how to get `class1` from the module object.

Comment: `path1`'s value is acquired dynamically. I changed the example to reflect that.

Comment: Did you read this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547829/how-to-dynamically-load-a-python-class
From the first answer of Jason Baker: " What you're basically wanting to do is this:   from my_package.my_module import my_class" 
It seems to me very similar to what you want to do

Comment: Yeah but he has something like `path.to.file`, while I can have `r'c:/folder_that_is_not_even_in_the_package/package_name/path/to/file.py'`. I guess I can write something to convert between the two but that seems wrong

Comment: In case someone else needs it. Your solution almost works, but you need `spec.loader.exec_module(module)`  after `module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)`.