# ModuleNotFoundError when using importlib inside of a class

Tags: python, class, modulenotfounderror, python-importlib

I am attempting to import an object using `importlib.import_module`, but am getting a `ModuleNotFoundError` no matter what I try. I've read through as many related posts as I can find, but haven't been able to solve my problem.

Thank you in advance to anyone able to help!

My project folder is structured like this:

```
root/
   checks.py
   database.py
   main.py
```

checks.py is where I define the `Check` class. It contains the following code.

```py
class Check():
    def __init__(self, action):
        self.action = action

    def speak(self):
        print(self.action)

class CheckOne(Check):
    def __init__(self):
        Check.__init__(self, "Performing the first check.")

    def apply_(self):
        self.speak()
```

database.py is where I define the `Database` class. It contains the following code.

```py
class Database():
    def __init__(self):
        # The checks we want to perform
        self.check_names = ['CheckOne']
    
    def apply_checks(self):
        import importlib
        checks = [importlib.import_module(f'checks.{i}') for i in self.check_names]
        for c in checks:
            c().apply_()
```

main.py instantiates a `Database` object and calls `apply_checks`. It contains the following code:

```py
from database import Database

db = Database()
db.apply_checks()
```

When I run main.py, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'checks.CheckOne'; 'checks' is not a package
```

What I am intending is that `Database.apply_checks` imports the `CheckOne` class into a list, instantiates it, and then executes the `CheckOne.apply_` method (printing `"Performing the first check."`).

I've tried placing `import checks` and `from . import checks` inside the `Database` class definition but to no avail. I've also tried adding an `__init__.py` file under `root`.

Thank you for reading, I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: It's right there in the error message: "'checks' is not a package". checks is a module. You're trying to import a class in a module as if it were a module inside a package; that doesn't work. `import_module` is meant to import a module, not a class (or any attribute of a module).

Comment: Thank you! It always is "right there in the error message"... But I didn't understand the difference. Your comment led me to a different question, and eventually the solution. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```py
import checks

class Database():
    def __init__(self):
        # The checks we want to perform
        self.check_names = ['CheckOne']
    
    def apply_checks(self):
        check_classes = [getattr(checks, name) for name in self.check_names]
        for cls in check_classes:
            cls().apply_()
```

Comment: That works, thank you! I happened to find the answer in this post as well, at the same time as you posted this. Marking your answer as accepted.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547829/how-to-dynamically-load-a-python-class