# how to dynamically create an instance of a class in python?

Tags: python

I have list of class names and want to create their instances dynamically. for example:

```
names=[
'foo.baa.a',
'foo.daa.c',
'foo.AA',
 ....
]

def save(cName, argument):
 aa = create_instance(cName) # how to do it?
 aa.save(argument)

save(random_from(names), arg)
```

How to dynamically create that instances in Python? thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is often referred to as reflection or sometimes introspection.  Check out a similar questions that have an answer for what you are trying to do:

[Does Python Have An Equivalent to Java Class forname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname)

[Can You Use a String to Instantiate a Class in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553784/can-you-use-a-string-to-instantiate-a-class-in-python)

Comment: Some of those examples use `__import__`, for newer code you can switch to `importlib` http://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html . (py>=2.7 | >=3.1)

Comment: Don't use links, please provide a real description.

Answer (score 102):

Assuming you have already imported the relevant classes using something like

```
from [app].models import *
```

all you will need to do is

```
klass = globals()["class_name"]
instance = klass()
```

Comment: Why did you name it `klass`? Does this word have a special meaning?

Comment: Works with django models

Comment: @Nyxynyx check out the programming concept of a "reserved word;" you typically want to avoid word that are commonly used as object and function names in the language and libraries you are using

Comment: to lean into the assumption here... this requires that the class already exist, whereas I want to define a new class with a dynamic name

Answer (score 22):

This worked for me:

```
from importlib import import_module

class_str: str = 'A.B.YourClass'
try:
    module_path, class_name = class_str.rsplit('.', 1)
    module = import_module(module_path)
    return getattr(module, class_name)
except (ImportError, AttributeError) as e:
    raise ImportError(class_str)
```

Comment: Works great for me! Thank you!!

Comment: Yeah, using importlib to resolve the class is way better than handling it manually with anti-patterns like star-imports. This answer is, as of python 3.3, the best solution.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the python builtin `eval()` statement to instantiate your classes.
Like this:

```
aa = eval(cName)()
```

***Notice!***

**using eval is dangerous and is a key for lots of security risks based on code injections.**

Comment: Don't use eval as it is susceptible to security issues.

Comment: and how is it susceptible?

Comment: Depends of the context, if `cName` comes from some input from a user, it's dangers because a hacker can inject Python code there: it's true, but many times you only need this to setup your application from a text file or an environment variable that is controlled only by developers / admins, in this case is secure enough and simple.

Comment: The security issue exist even when not using `eval` as attacker can instanciate any class he wants. My point is: this implementation requirement should be furthered analyzed to be secure.

Answer (score 9):

You can often avoid the string processing part of this entirely.

```
import foo.baa 
import foo.AA
import foo

classes = [ foo.baa.a, foo.daa.c, foo.AA ]

def save(theClass, argument):
   aa = theClass()
   aa.save(argument)

save(random.choice(classes), arg)
```

Note that we don't use a string representation of the name of the class.

In Python, you can just use the class itself.

Comment: Suppose that array comes from database. So this solution does not help.

Comment: well you just do `type(cName)(**arguments)`

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I wanted to pass arguments into `__init__` with the arguments being specified in a string on the command line.  For example, the equivalent of

```
import a.b.ClassB as ClassB
instance = ClassB.ClassB('World')
```

The string on the command line is `"a.b.ClassB.ClassB('World')"`

With the following class in module a.b.ClassB

```
class ClassB():

    def __init__(self, name:str):
        self._name = name

    def hello(self):
        print("Hello " + self._name + "!")
```

we can create this class with the following

```
import importlib

def create_instance(class_str:str):
    """
    Create a class instance from a full path to a class constructor
    :param class_str: module name plus '.' plus class name and optional parens with arguments for the class's
        __init__() method. For example, "a.b.ClassB.ClassB('World')"
    :return: an instance of the class specified.
    """
    try:
        if "(" in class_str:
            full_class_name, args = class_name = class_str.rsplit('(', 1)
            args = '(' + args
        else:
            full_class_name = class_str
            args = ()
        # Get the class object
        module_path, _, class_name = full_class_name.rpartition('.')
        mod = importlib.import_module(module_path)
        klazz = getattr(mod, class_name)
        # Alias the the class so its constructor can be called, see the following link.
        # See https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval
        alias = class_name + "Alias"
        instance = eval(alias + args, { alias: klazz})
        return instance
    except (ImportError, AttributeError) as e:
        raise ImportError(class_str)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    instance = create_instance("a.b.ClassB.ClassB('World')")
    instance.hello()
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Answer I found:
Better Way is to make a dictionary:
objects ={}
Names =[object1,object2, object3]

For objname in Names:
   objects[objname]=classname()

Found in:
https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/create-object-name-from-string-value.712461/