# Python - How to call static member using class string?

Tags: python

I have a variable

`class_name = "BigClass"`

i need to access Class `BigClass` static members like this `BigClass.static_data`

can i somehow convert the string inside variable `class_name` into an actual class and access its static members in Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553784/can-you-use-a-string-to-instantiate-a-class-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class BigClass:
    static_data = 42

    def foo(self):
        return "frog"

bc = eval("BigClass" + "()")
print bc.foo()
print bc.static_data
```

If you just want to access the static data then you can drop the "()" from the eval call.

Another approach is to use a class decorator to register the class in a lookup table (dictionary) and provide a lookup_class function.  I like the second approach better, eval can be dangerous.

```
_cls_lookup = {}
def register_cls(cls):
    _cls_lookup[cls.__name__] = cls        
    return cls

def lookup_cls(cls_name):
    return _cls_lookup[cls_name]

@register_cls
class BigClass:
    static_data = 42

bc = lookup_cls("BigClass")
print bc.static_data
```