# How do I create objects dynamically in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to be able to have multiple entries with unique Return functions in my program using tkinter.

What I have right now is a for loop with the following:

```py
...
parent = Frame(self, ...)

# values is a dictionary containing a name for each Label  
# and a list of user input and a certain command

for key, value in values.items():
    temp_name_frame = Frame(parent)  
    temp_name_frame.pack(fill="none", expand="no", anchor='w')  

    temp_name_label = Label(temp_name_frame, text=key, width=30, anchor='w')  
    temp_name_label.pack(side=LEFT, anchor='w')  

    temp_name_entry = Entry(temp_name_frame, width=20)  
    temp_name_entry.pack(side=LEFT)
    temp_name_entry.insert(END, value[0])
    temp_name_entry.bind('<Return>', lambda e: send_command(value[1]))     
...
```

**Exptected Outcome:**
When I run the program the expected outcome is a Frame `parent` with multiple frames `temp_name_frame` inside. In each of those frames a Label `temp_name_label` with text `key` and Entry `temp_name_entry` with value `value[0]` is present and each Entry has a unique command `value[1]` on Return.

**Actual Outcome:**
When I run the program the outcome is a Frame `parent` with multiple frames `temp_name_frame` inside. In each of those frames a Label `temp_name_label` with text `key` and Entry `temp_name_entry` with value `value[0]` is present, **but** each Entry has the last command `value[1]` from the values dictionary on Return.

I believe this is because each Frame, Label and Entry is overwritten because the name of each variable stays the same (`temp_name_frame`, `temp_name_label`, `temp_name_entry`)

But if that is true, why do I have multiple Labels and Entries with the correct Label text and Entry value?

**Another** example explained without code:
I have 3 Labels that have an indentifying name as text like `Unique command 1 Label`, `Unique command 2 Label` and `Unique command 3 Label` respectively.
I have 3 Entries that on return print something like `Unique command 1`, `Unique command 2` and `Unique command 3` respectively and each Entry value on startup is 1, 2, and 3 respectively.

**Outcome:**
Each Label has the correct text: `Unique command 1 Label`, `Unique command 2 Label`, `Unique command 3 Label`
Each Entry has the correct value at startup (1, 2 and 3)
BUT each Entry returns 'Unique command 3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have run into a fairly common problem of late binding in Python. You can read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677649/tkinter-assign-button-command-in-loop-with-lambda) for more details.

Basically you need to force a closure in your `lambda` function, like so:

```
...

def send_command(event, string): #just a made up function
    print (string)

for key, value in values.items():
    ...
    temp_name_entry.bind('<Return>', lambda e, v=value[1]: send_command(e, v))
```

Answer (score -1):

This is often referred to as reflection or sometimes introspection. Check out a similar questions that have an answer for what you are trying to do:

[Does Python Have An Equivalent to Java Class forname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname)

[Can You Use a String to Instantiate a Class in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553784/can-you-use-a-string-to-instantiate-a-class)