# How to make a new object while the program is running

Tags: python, list, object

I am currently making 2048 and am having trouble with creating a new block whenever a move is made.

I made a list storing all the blocks there are, within the list there objects:

```
class Blocks:
   ~~~~~~~ code ~~~~~~~~~

block1 = Blocks()
block2 = Blocks()
block_list = [block1, block2]
```

The issue is that it works perfectly when the blocks are pre-written, but I can not make a new block while the game is already running, is there any way to do this? Thank you in advance, stay safe :)

Comment: Note that `block1 = Blocks()` already creates an instance of the `Blocks` class while the program is running. You do something similar on each move.

Comment: As a point of clarification, what does the class `Blocks` represent? Is it all of the blocks on the screen? Or is it just a single block? If so, I suggest removing the "s" from the end of the class name.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice "Blocks" is a class that represents one block and within a list, there are objects of that class that can fill up the screen. I will definitely take your suggestion to remove the "s" so thank you so much! but I still don't really know how to for example add an object to the list while the program is already running, I know I need to ".append" something but im not exactly sure how to.

Comment: As the answer below shows, you create a new `Blocks` object, just like you do with the first two then you append that object to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why this would not be possible. You should simply be able append a new block to your block_list:

```
block_n = Blocks()
block_list.append(block_n)
```

You place this in your game loop where you detect when a move is made.

Where you blit I assume you go through the block_list and blit all the blocks to the screen? Also make sure to always update the screen with pygame.display.flip().

Answer (score -1):

1. I suppose that you need "Reflection" in python. Reflection can get type of instance, create instance of type during code runtime.
2. You can get some inspirations from the question [Can you use a string to instantiate a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/554812/15073910)  or the article [Classes and Class Creation](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_classes_and_type.php)

Comment: No reflection is required here. The name of the class is known in the code and doesn't need to come from a string.