# Mapping URLs to Classes in python - library

Tags: python, url, mapping

which is a library that will map URLS is classes in python like web.py does? like:

```
URLS = (
    '/', 'index',
    '/browser/set/(.*)', 'browser_set',
    '/captcha', 'captcha',
    '/product', 'product',
    '/lang/set/(.*)', 'lang_set',
    '/(.*)', 'redir',
    )
```

i looked on web.py's code to find the part that does that exact thing to extract it and use it  as a standalone library but couldn't find it.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176136/convert-string-to-python-class-object

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you are trying to build a web server, why not use web.py?

Comment: i can't get web.py to work. i tried python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.3. it just doesn't work. that plus it would be better for me to just get this part of the code, as that's just what i want to do.