# Django REST framework, get object from URL

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm wondering if there is a clean way to retrieve an object from its URL with django rest framework. Surely there should be, as it seems to be what's happening when using `HyperlinkedRelatedField`.

For instance, I have this URL `/api/comment/26` as a string. From my view, how can I get the comment instance with `pk=26`?

Of course I could redo the work and work on the string but it must be a better way?

Thanks a lot.

### EDIT:

This is how I solved it at the end:

`resolve('/api/comment/26/').func.cls.model` will return my model Comment.
`resolve('/api/category/1/').kwargs['pk']` will return the pk.

Which gives you:

```python
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

resolved_func, unused_args, resolved_kwargs = resolve('/api/category/1/')
resolved_func.cls.model.objects.get(pk=resolved_kwargs['pk'])
```

Comment: Remember that if you have a fully qualified URL (e.g. starting with "http...") you need to extract its `path` and pass that to `resolve`. This can be done with the [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) module.

Comment: I didn't look into it to much but for me resolved_func.cls returns the view set so I needed to use the following to get to the model: resolved_func.cls.serializer_class.Meta.model.objects.get(pk=resolved_kwargs['pk'])

Comment: This is not working with django 2.1 and python 3.5 anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your best bet would be to manually keep a map of models to url patterns — not too dissimilar from a `URLConf`.

If that doesn't rock your boat you could [pass the path into `resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve).

This will give you a `ResolverMatch` upon which you'll find the `func` that was returned by the `as_view` call when you set up your URLs.

The `__name__` attribute of your view function will be that of your original view class. Do something like [`globals()[class_name]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1176179/102260) to get the class itself.

From there access the `model` attribute.

I hope that helps. As I say, you might just want to map models to URLs yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!!
Nearly there, I tweaked a bit your answer to get exactly want I needed that way: `resolve('/api/category/1/').func.cls.model`

Comment: Ah, `...func.cls` is there is it? — Never needed it but that's much cleaner. Thank you to you too!

Answer (score 2):

With class-based views, something like the following seems needed:

```
resolve(url).func.cls.serializer_class.Meta.model.objects.get(
    **resolve(url).kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution above did not work for me, the following did work though:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

resolved_func, unused_args, resolved_kwargs = resolve('/api/category/1/')
resolved_func.cls().get_queryset().get(id=resolved_kwargs['pk'])
```

additionally this solution uses the built in queryset of your view, which might have annotations or important filters.

Using HyperlinkedModelSerializer I actually needed to do this with a full url. For this to work, you need to extract the path first, resulting in:

```
import urllib.parse
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

def obj_from_url(url):
    path = urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path
    resolved_func, unused_args, resolved_kwargs = resolve(path)
    return resolved_func.cls().get_queryset().get(id=resolved_kwargs['pk'])
```

Comment: `django.core.urlresolvers` module has been removed in Django 2.0 and url-related functions (like `resolve`) has been moved to `django.urls`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve