# Introspecting for locally-scoped classes (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

While trying to use introspection to navigate from strings to classes via some of the suggestions in [Convert string to Python class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176136/convert-string-to-python-class-object) I noticed that the given approaches won't work to get at a class in scope local to a function. Consider the following code:

```
import sys

def f():
   class LocalClass:
       pass
   print LocalClass
   print 'LocalClass' in dir(sys.modules[__name__])
```

which gives output

```
__main__.LocalClass
False
```

I'm a bit confused as to why LocalClass seems to belong to the main module according to the class object itself, and yet not accessible through sys.modules. Can someone give an explanation?

And is there a way to generate a class from a string, even if that class is only in non-global scope?

Comment: the `dir` function returns globals the way you are using it.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `f`, `LocalClass` is indeed local. You can see this by trying `__main__.LocalClass` and seeing that `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LocalClass'` is raised.

As to why the class returns `__main__.LocalClass` is because by default, the `__repr__` function returns `<cls.__module__>.<cls.__name__>`.

The reason why `dir` isn't finding it is because it only looks at the variables defined in its scope. `LocalClass` is local so it won't show up if you are looking in the main module.

A way to create a class from a string can be done in many ways.

The first and easiest to understand is by using `exec`. Now you shouldn't just go around using `exec` for random things so I wouldn't reccomend using this method.

The second method is by using the `type` function. The help page for it returns `type(name, bases, dict)`. This means you can create a class called `LocalClass` subclassed by `object` with the attribute `foo` set to "bar" by doing `type("LocalClass", (object,), {"foo": "bar"})` and catching the returned class in a variable. You can make the class global by doing `globals()["LocalClass"] = ...`

PS: An easier (not sure if prettier) way to get the main module is by doing `import __main__`. This can be used in any module but I would generally advise against using this unless you know what you are doing because in general, python people don't like you doing this sort of thing.

EDIT: after looking at the linked question, you dont want to dynamically create a new class but to retrieve a variable given it's name.  All the answers in the linked question will do that. I'll leave you up to deciding which one you prefer the most

EDIT2: `LocalClass.__module__` is the same as `__main__` because that was the module you defined the class. If you had defined it in module `Foo` that was imported by `__main__` (and not actually ran standalone), you would find that `__module__` would be "B". Even though `LocalClass` was defined in `__main__`, it won't automatically go into the global table just because it is a class - in python, as you might have already known, (almost) EVERYTHING is an object. The `dir` function searches for all variables defined in a scope. As you are looking in the main scope, it is nearly equivalent to be doing `__dict__` or `globals()` but with some slight differences. Because `LocalClass` is local, it isn't defined in the global context. If however you did `locals()` whilst inside the function `f`, you would find that `LocalClass` would appear in that list

Comment: Hm.. but why is `LocalClass.__module__` equal to `__main__` if at the same time `dir` tells us `LocalClass` doesn't belong to the main module?

As for the second part - sorry if the question wasn't clear, but I'm not trying to define a new class in local scope from a string - rather I'm trying to get an instance of the classobj corresponding to that string.