# How to pass a class constructor to a python function

Tags: python, function, class, constructor

Suppose I have a class `Foo`, I want to define a function that receives the class constructor as a parameter:

```
def bar(class_name):
    local_class = None
    # TODO: if I call bar(Foo()), I want to get local_class = Foo()
```

How can I implement the function?

Comment: When you would call `bar(Foo())` , you would call `bar()` function with an instance of `Foo()` ,can't you directly use that instance?

Comment: `Foo()` is not the class constructor.  If you want to pass the class, you would pass `Foo`.

Comment: Just past the class, `bar(Foo)`, then `local_class = class_name()` would create an instance of Foo.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Inside the function, I want to get multiple independent instances of the class using the parameter ``class_name``

Comment: @achampion What if ``Foo`` takes parameters? For example, ``bar(Foo(1,2,3))``

Comment: @beaver `bar(functools.partial(Foo, 1, 2, 3))`

Comment: @AnandSKumar I want to pass something that generally generates one object of a class, such as ``Foo(1,2,3)``, so that inside the function ``bar``, I can get multiple independent objects, all of which should be equivalent to be created as ``Foo(1,2,3)``

Comment: @HuazuoGao I am sorry but it's a little inelegant to call the function.

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is `deepcopy` -- https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy

Answer (score 12):

The following `bar` function will work. Note, the first parameter will be a *class* itself and not the name of a class, so "`class_name`", which implies that it's a `str`, is misleading. `args` will be a tuple of args to initialize `klass` objects with, *-unpacked in the calls to `klass`. You said in a later comment that you wanted to "create multiple independent objects", all of the same class and initialized with the same args, so I've revised my answer to reflect that:

```
def bar(klass, *args):
    # Now you can create multiple independent objects of type klass,
    # all initialized with the same args
    obj1 = klass(*args)
    obj2 = klass(*args)
    # ...
    # do whatever you have in mind with the objs
```

Your "`local_class`" isn't a class at all, but rather an instance of `klass`, so that's a bad name; and anyway you want several of them.

Assuming `Foo` objects are initialized with three int arguments, and `Baz` objects with two strings, you can call `bar` like so:

```
bar(Foo, 1, 2, 3)
bar(Baz, 'Yo', 'bro')
```

etc.

Especially in a dynamically-typed language like Python, reasoning about code is more difficult when variables have misleading names.

Answer (score 1):

When can pass the classname as an argument to your function, and then call `class_name()`. E.g., if you also want to pass arguments.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        pass

def bar1(class_name):
    args = ("val1", "val2")
    local_class = class_name(*args)
```

or

```
def bar2(class_name):
    kwargs = {'arg1':'val1','arg2':'val2'}
    local_class = class_name(**kwargs)
```

You can call the functions like:

```
one = bar1(Foo)
two = bar2(Foo)
```

If you really want to call the class from a string read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176136/convert-string-to-python-class-object) post. I would suggest you use @Evan Fosmark's solution because use of `eval` and `globals` should be avoided