# Is there a magic function which is used to parse raw string into object?

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization

As we know, there are `__str__` and `__repr__` convert object into `str`, but is there any magic function that I can used to do the exact opposite thing? For example, I have

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return '({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)
```

I can get `(1, 2)` if I call `print(Point(1, 2))` and assume I saved it into a file. And now, if I want to recover it from the file. Is there any magic function that I can overload to parse the raw string into object? Just like what the `<<` operator does in C++, and what the `Read` class does in Haskell.

Emm, I'm not sure if this just is what called serialization and deserialization.

**UPDATE**

I just want a magic function's name, which play the role of placeholder, when I want to parse a raw string into a object, I just come to this name. I'm not asking how to parse. So this is not duplicated with [Convert strig to Python class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176136/convert-string-to-python-class-object).

Comment: yes, it is serialization and deserialization

Comment: look at `json.dumps()` to write it to a file, then `json.load()` to recreat your object.