# Python: How to create a class object using Importlib

Tags: python, python-importlib

I know a similar question has been asked/answered several times. But please do read on ..

I am trying to create a Class from a string value as described in "[Convert string to Python Class Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176136/convert-string-to-python-class-object)" in Python 3.6.

**utils.py**

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("In the constructor of Foo")

    def What(self):
        print("so what ... ")

class FooParam(object):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.value = v
        print("In the constructor of FooParam")

    def What(self):
        print("Value=" % self.value)
        print("So what now ...")
```

**welcome.py**

```
def TEST1():
    m = importlib.import_module("utils")
    c = getattr(m, "Foo")
    c.What()  

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    TEST1()
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: What() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

So what am I doing wrong ?

Also how can I create an object of "FooParam" and pass a value to the constructor.

Comment: _"how can I create an object of "FooParam" and pass a value to the constructor."_ -> You call its constructor with an argument. `FooParam = getattr(m, "FooParam"); obj = FooParam(whatever)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that c is the class Foo but not an instance of the class.

This is equivalent to simply calling

```
Foo.what()
```

Which is why self is not defined!

Whereas what you want is to create an instance of the class (giving it a 'self' property), then call its method, i.e.

```
foo_instance = Foo()
foo_instance.What()
```

so try replacing c.What() with..

```
foo_instance = c()
foo_instance.What()
```

for FooParam:

```
#import the class FooParam
c = getattr(m, "FooParam")
#create an instance of the class, initializing its values (and self)
fooparam_instance = c(3.14)
#call its method!
fooparam_instance.What()
```

on the whole I would rename the variable c, to something like foo_import and fooparam_import respectively :)

Answer (score 2):

Once you import the module just access with the variable you stored imported module:

```
m = importlib.import_module("utils")
foo = m.Foo()
foo.What()
```

`import_module` performs the same steps as `import`.

This `c = getattr(m, "Foo")` line of code is equivalent `f = Foo` so that means you are not creating an instance instead you are getting a reference to that class.

Comment: Thank you both for the answer. It is embarrasing to have missed an important point of the importlib. It works now.