# How to speed up importing variable named modules via importlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib

I'm scratching my head to come up with a fast way to import my custom python files whose names are variable and decided by input. What I'm trying to do is have my entrypoint send data to other classes for processing.

Folder structure:

```
root/
├─ dir1/
│  ├─ file1.py
├─ entrypoint.py
├─ dir2/
├─ dir3/
```

Everything I've tried, except just doing a direct `from dir1 import file1` takes 2-3 seconds, which is too long for my usage and makes me think that `importlib` is scanning through all other directories before finally finding the correct module.

I've tried this with `importlib`:

```
input_dir = "dir1"
input_file = "file1"

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(input_file,
            f'{os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}/{input_dir}/{input_file}.py')
class_ = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(class_)
```

Comment: The code you've posted will unconditionally create a new module object and run the contents of `file1.py`, even if `file1.py` has already been loaded by a previous execution of the same code. Is that what you want to happen? (Normal imports don't do that.)

Comment: And why aren't you just doing `module = importlib.import_module(whatever_fully_qualified_name)`?

Comment: Great question @user2357112supportsMonica & an even better observation. I had no idea it would have that kind of effect, I should probably spend some more time in documentation to have it click. I first tried importlib.import_module but it went back to taking 2-3 seconds after calling getattr() to get to the class.

I think I just found an answer to how to avoid using getattr() here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434118/python-how-to-create-a-class-object-using-importlib -- gotta test this tomorrow