# Convert a python string to an sklearn classifier object

Tags: python, scikit-learn

If i have a string:

```
"ExtraTreesClassifier(bootstrap=False, class_weight=None, max_depth=None, max_features=11, min_samples_leaf=2, min_samples_split=8, n_estimators=20, criterion="gini", n_jobs=4, random_state=12)"
```

What is the best way to convert it to an sklearn classifier so that i can fit my dataset to it?

Desired output:

```
<class 'sklearn.ensemble.forest.ExtraTreesClassifier'>
```

**EDIT**

In my case, the string is not wrapped in hyphens (understand that without the hypens i will be able to call the sklearn function), rather the variable is of type string.

**SOLUTION**

I have managed to solve it by first extracting the parameters to dictionary form, then placing it within the sklearn estimator:

```
import ast

ExtraTreesClassifier(**ast.literal_eval("{"+i.split("(", 1)[1][:-1].replace("=",":")+"}"))
```

`i.split("(", 1)[1][:-1]` removes `"ExtraTreesClassifier("` and `")"` from the string.

To format string to the same syntax as a dictionary, use:
`.replace("=",":")` then wrap brackets `"{"`

Because this is still a string representation of a dictionary, to pass it as parameters to the sklearn estimator, this is needed to be wrapped around the dictionary:
`**ast.literal_eval()` -> see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary) link

Comment: Use `eval` althought it's not recommended

Comment: that string is the call for instantiating the `ExtraTreesClassifier` object. do `my_classifier =ExtraTreesClassifier(bootstrap=False, class_weight=None, max_depth=None, max_features=11, min_samples_leaf=2, min_samples_split=8, n_estimators=20, criterion="gini", n_jobs=4, random_state=12) `

Comment: @sshashank124oh i have tried that before.. but will face this error: SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to Python class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176136/convert-string-to-python-class-object)

Comment: Post the solution as an answer and accept it