# How to reference a class from a string which is part of a variable 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

I have just read a text file and extracted a string and stored it as a variable. This string also happens to be the name of a class I want to reference in order to use in a function for example. The "which_class" variable is the whichever class was stored in the file

I tried passing the which_class variable in as a parameter to the function. Removing the quotations seems to make it work but I am unsure how to do this.

```
class needed_for_func_one():
    multiplier = 1.23

class needed_for_func_two():
    multiplier = 1.15


def random_function(which_class):
    print(123 * which_class.multiplier)

PSEUDO CODE
READ FROM FILE STORE STRING AS "which_class"

which_class = "needed_for_func_two"


random_function(which_class)
```

But this didn't work it just gave me an attribute error

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176136/convert-string-to-python-class-object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `eval` function could help you here.

```
random_function(eval(whichClass))
```

However, you should probably rethink whether you really want to it that way or if there is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks, works great. It is quite janky I know but it seems to work as quick solution for a small problem

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)
How you call the function depends if it is a global function or if it is inside an object.

```
globals()['call_this_function']() # this is probably what you need
```

or

```
getattr(from_this_object, 'call_this_function')()
```

Answer (score 0):

first, to use a class you need an object of a class.
so if what you read is a name of the class or any other thing it does not matter, just use an if statement to decide what is inside that variable so-called "which_class".
then create an object like :

```
if which_class=="needed_for_func_one":
    newObject = needed_for_func_one()
elseif which_class=="needed_for_func_two":
    newObject = needed_for_func_two()
```

then use the print like :

```
print(123 * newObject.multiplier )
```