# Python string to Class name

Tags: python, python-3.x

How does one convert a string to the name of a class in Python? For example, if I have a series of related classes such as `MyClass1`, `MyClass2`, `MyClassN...`, how do I call the class I need if I were in a conditional assuming only the ending number of the string were to change?

**Edit:**
All the classes are already defined. I just need a way to call them depending on the situation. The number will be coming from a GET variable so it would be nice if I can just append that number to a string.

Comment: There's nothing special about class names. Those are just regular variables. Classes are just objects, like any other. A natural way to map strings to objects is to use a `dict`. Or in your case, maybe a `list`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to Python class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176136/convert-string-to-python-class-object)

Comment: @enchance just use a dict. That is the cleanest solution. If all the classes are in the global scope in the module you need them, then you can just use the `globals()` dict, although that's sort of hacky. Better to just make your own dictionary to keep things clean

Comment: Also, if they're in a different module, you can use `getattr` to dynamically use a class from an imported module: `getattr(module, 'MyClass{}'.format(num))`