# Querying from AJAX in Django (GET)

Tags: python, django

I have a template (`menu.html`), and I am making an AJAX call with JavaScript. Then, I want to process that call (throughout the GET parameters) and make a query from Django's ORM. \

My JavaScript code is:

```
$.ajax("/showcart", {
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            product: product,
            type: product_type
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("SUCCES SUCCESS SUCCESS")
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(resp) {
            console.log("ERROR ERROR ERROR!")
            console.log(resp)
        }

    })
```

`product` is the name of my product, and `product_type` is the size of my product. 
Then, in my `views.py`, I handle this call with:

```
def showcart(request):
    product = request.GET['product']
    if request.GET['type'] == "small":
        size = f"{request.GET['type']}_price"
    elif request.GET['type'] == "large":
        size = f"{request.GET['type']}_price"
    else:
        size = "price"

    product_name = product.split("-")[0]
    product_id = product.split("-")[1]

    return JsonResponse(
        {
        "product_name": product_name,
        "product_id": product_id,
        "size": size,
        "queryresult": "nothing here",
        }
    )
```

For example, `product_name` is "Sub" and I have a model in `models.py` called Sub. My goal is querying the price, for instance, with the `product_name`. But, since it is a `string` type, Django doesn't allow me to do that. Does anyone know how this works?

Thanks,

Comment: I find it unclear... Please show your `models.py`. Also, you said sthg about queryset but, there is no queryset.

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane What I mean is, I get a `product_name` "Sub", and my model's name is Sub and has a field `price`. I want to use `product_name.objects.get(...)` but Django throws an error saying that `product_name` is a string. How can I use that variable when querying from `models.py`?

Comment: Okay... now I get what you are asking. Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176136/convert-string-to-python-class-object ?