# Trying to use f' string to print out a list but not the string

Tags: list, f-string

I'm trying to print out a list using a following code:

```
list_1 = [1,2,3]
list_2 = [1,2,3,4]
list_3 = [1,2,3,7,9]
list_4 = [1,2,7,11,12,15]

for x in range(1,5):
    print(f'list_{x}')

print(list_1)
```

which outputs the following:

```
list_1
list_2
list_3
list_4
[1, 2, 3]
```

I would like the first f'string list_1 to out put the list as in the final output.

Is there a string type that I need to convert my f'string into first or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Just did some further investigation - it seems I needed to convert my string to a class and it now does the trick!

[Convert string to Python class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176136/convert-string-to-python-class-object)