# Python type conversion using variable value

Tags: python

```
mytype = "int" 
myvalue = "35"
my_int_val = mytype(myvalue)
```

This throws up -

`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

I can't seem to remember the way to do so. Any ideas?

Please note that I have to use "str", "int" instead of str or int (without quotes), because I am getting this value from somewhere else where it's being passed on as a string.

Comment: `my_int_val = int(myvalue)`

Comment: you aren't writing a function around myvalue. You are calling a variable on a variable.

Try str("35") that works as str is a function and "str" within mytype is a string

Comment: Errors aside, why would you expect `str("35")` to return an integer value?

Comment: @JohnGordon I've corrected my question. I meant to say int instead of str.

Comment: What you have now is equivalent to `my_int_val = "int"("35")`. The *name* of (a reference to) a type is not the same thing as the type itself. As types are first-class values in Python, you can define `mytype = int`, and the rest of your code will work as you expect.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use any builtin function dynamically to convert the data you can fetch it from `__builtins__`.

```
mytype = "str"
myvalue = "34"

func = getattr(__builtins__, mytype)

print(func(myvalue))
print(type(func(myvalue)))
```

This will give you

```
34
<class 'str'>
```

If you use `mytype = "float"` you'll get

```
34.0
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: Thanks - That is how I intend to use it (str, float, int etc)

Comment: If you're going to do this, why not just say `mytype = str`?  Then you don't need a lookup at all.  You already have the actual `str` type object.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_int_val = int(myvalue)
my_str_val = str(myvalue)
```

is the cleanest way to do this. But for some reason if you want the type to be stored in a string and call it, you can use eval:

```py
t = "int"
my_int_val = eval(f"{t}({myvalue})")
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `eval` until I really need to. In nearly 20 years of Python programming I used it once. A must read: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). You shouldn't use `eval` until you read and unterstood his article and after you read and understood it you don't want to use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`mytype` is a variable not a datatype

```
int_val = int(myvalue)
str_val = str(myvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

my try:

```
mytype = "int"
myvalue = "35"
#my_int_val = myvalue.type(mytype)


my_int_val = eval(mytype)(myvalue)  


print(my_int_val, type(my_int_val))

mytype = "str"
myvalue = 35

print(myvalue, type(myvalue))

my_int_val = eval(mytype)(myvalue)

print(my_int_val, type(my_int_val))
```

output:

```
35 <class 'int'>
35 <class 'int'>
35 <class 'str'>
```

but need to confess I copied from here : [Convert string to Python class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176136/convert-string-to-python-class-object)

oops didnt notice answer above, in any case :

> Warning: eval() can be used to execute arbitrary Python code. You   should never use eval() with untrusted strings. ([Security of Python's eval() on untrusted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `mytype = "str"` just do `mytype = str` and it will work (as it sets mytype to the builtin function str).

Example with a function:

```
def cast(value, totype):
    return totype(value)

mystr = cast(35, str)
print(mystr, type(mystr))

myfloat = cast("35", float)
print(myfloat, type(myfloat))
```

Output:

```
35 <class 'str'>
35.0 <class 'float'>
```