# Use name of a class as a parameter of a function in Python to make it work for several class types

Tags: python, parameter-passing, class-variables

I write a function that gets a `filename`, reads out information from the file and creates a `Read` object out of it.

```
def read_file(filename):   
  with open(filename, 'r') as filetoread:
        readList = []
        for line in filetoread:
            readList.append(Read(line))
        return readList
```

This implementation works.

Now I want to generalize my function and make it work for two object/class types: `Read` and `Reference`.
So I want to use a class name as a parameter of a function.
The function gets a `filename` and a `classname` now. It reads out information from the file and creates an object of a specified `classname` out of it.

My attempt lookes like this.

```
def read_file(filename, classname):
  with open(filename, 'r') as filetoread:
        readList = []
        for line in filetoread:
            readList.append(classname(line))
        return readList
```

I get TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.

My idea was using this solution:

```
def str_to_class(classname):
    return getattr(sys.modules[__name__], classname)
```

Source: [Convert string to Python class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176136/convert-string-to-python-class-object)

I still get an error though (TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string)

Comment: No? If you already have `Reference` then why do you need that function at all?

Comment: It would help to know what you are trying to accomplish. As @DeepSpace said, I don't see what the purpose of this is, if you already have `Reference`

Comment: The thing is that I have to implement a function that would create objects out of a file. So the function gets a filename and a name of a class and depending on the user input two different class types could be created. Like this: def read(file, classname).
So if classname is "Reference" - Reference object should be created and if the classname is "Read" - Read Object should be created

Comment: This is clearly an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info). You should ask about your actual problem.

Comment: @DeepSpace, you are right. I have modified my question

Comment: @Hutch I tried to explain what I try to accomplish in my question update. Sorry for being not clear.

Comment: @DeepSpace Is my question/ problem understandable now?

Comment: @Kate_teryna Where is this file coming from? Are you saving the state of your objects to a file?

It sounds like you are trying to do some serialization/deserialization. Does that sound accurate?

Comment: I added an answer, but without the larger context, it's hard to say what the proper way to handle this would be. I would look into serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.` is telling you your problem.

For an object to be "callable" it must implement the `__callable__()` magic method. Strings do not implement this method, and therefore you get this error.

But wait! You know what does implement `__callable__()`? Classes!

Now rather than trying to do some conversion, just pass in the raw characters. This classname is a `token` and will be treated as such.

Therefore when calling your function

Use: `read_file("myFile.txt", Read)`

and NOT: `read_file("myFile.txt", "Read")`

Answer (score -2):

Lets imagine you have a class A

```
class A:
    pass
```

If you call str the result should be `<class '__main__.A'>`:

```
str(A) == "<class '__main__.A'>"
```

for get class name you can use `__name__` method

```
str_to_class(Reference.__name__)
```

or modify your function to `str_or_class_to_class` ;-)

Comment: This is not what OP attempts to do. Anyway, what do *you* imagine to be a useful usage of `str_to_class(Reference.__name__)`? You already have `Reference`, why would you go `str_to_class(Reference.__name__)` -> `str_to_class("Reference")` just to get `Reference` back?

Comment: I dont know what OP attempts to do. You suggest to return class from `str_to_class` function if it accept classes. I think that is a good idea to rename and modify this function to str_or_class_to_class (my second suggestion).

Comment: But anyway, maybe for this issue is enough to use `Reference.__name__`, who knows?

Comment: Which would still make 0 sense, at all. Either way this shouldn't really be an answer.