# Initialise class object by name

Tags: python

Since everything in python is an object, i was wondering if there was a way i could initialise a class object using the name of the class

for example,

```
class Foo:
    """Class Foo"""
```

How could i access this class by "Foo", ie something like `c = get_class("Foo")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does python have an equivalent to Java Class.forName()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If the class is in your scope:

```
get_class = lambda x: globals()[x]
```

If you need to get a class from a module, you can use `getattr`:

```
import urllib2
handlerClass = getattr(urllib2, 'HTTPHandler')
```

Comment: Since this uses getattr, i could use this for a function object also right?

Comment: For a quick note, to get an instance of the class it would need to be globals()[x]().

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard of the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html)?

Check out [this snippet](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/553262-list-classes-methods-and-functions-in-a-module/) I found.

Comment: -1: OP wants to get a class by name, not list all classes names.

Answer (score -2):

I think your searching reflection 
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_science%29#Python

Or a better Example from the german wikipedia:

```
>>> # the object
>>> class Person(object):
...    def __init__(self, name):
...        self.name = name
...    def say_hello(self):
...        return 'Hallo %s!' % self.name
...
>>> ute = Person('Ute')
>>> # direct
>>> print ute.say_hello()
Hallo Ute!
>>> # Reflexion
>>> m = getattr(ute, 'say_hello')()
>>> # (equals ute.say_hello())
>>> print m
Hallo Ute!
```

from http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexion_%28Programmierung%29#Beispiel_in_Python

Comment: Your link and/or example do not answer the question at all.