# Python: Using reflection to invoke class members from the class name

Tags: python, reflection

If suppose i have a class name as a string, how can i use reflection to invoke its static member known before-hand? Some like this:

```
someInspectionMechanism("FooClass").staticMethod()
```

Comment: There is no global namespace for classes (and that's a good thing), so you better know where it's located.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030982/initialise-class-object-by-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `locals()` or `globals()` to get the namespace dictionary, and look for a class with the name you want. The fact that you're using a static method is not relevant.

Example:

```
class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def method():
        return 'called static method'

assert locals()['Test'].method() == 'called static method'
```

Comment: The fact that it is a static method _is_ relevant, as he would otherwise need to instantiate the object.

Comment: Yeah, but it's not relevant for getting access to the class.