# How to transform a string to a Class name in Python?

Tags: python, flask

I get a string *selected_optimizer* from HTML form

```py
selected_optimizer = str(request.form['optimizer'])
print(selected_optimizer) #AdamOptimizer
```

I recall function

```py
import tensorflow as tf

train_model(
    my_optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.05))
```

Is it possible to convert string as a Class name and get something like this:

```py
train_model(
    my_optimizer=tf.train.selected_optimizer(learning_rate=0.05))
```

Comment: try if else ladder.

Comment: `dict` mapping or reflection, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030982/initialise-class-object-by-name)

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary.

```
optimizers = {
    "AdamOptimizer": tf.train.AdamOptimizer,
    "OtherOptimizer": ....,
}
selected_optimizer = optimizers[request.form['optimizer']]
train_model(my_optimizer=selected_optimizer(learning_rate=0.05))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import tensorflow as tf

selected_optimizer = str(request.form['optimizer'])
print(selected_optimizer) #AdamOptimizer

eval("train_model(my_optimizer=tf.train."+selected_optimizer+"(learning_rate=0.05))")
```

using eval is easier than this. according to me

```
def AdamOptimizer():
    print("hi")

strr="AdamOptimizer"

eval(strr+'()')
```