# Reflection in python

Tags: python, django, reflection

I'm trying to find some info on reflection in python.  I found a wikipedia article which gave this as a code snippet:

```
# without reflection
Foo().hello()

# with reflection
getattr(globals()['Foo'](), 'hello')()
```

I wasn't able to get this to work.  What I really need is a way to just instantiate the object.  So if I have a string 'Foo' I want to be able to get an object of type Foo.  Like in java I could say something like: Class.forName("Foo")

Just found this...wonder why I couldn't find this before:
[Does python have an equivalent to Java Class.forName()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname)

Comment: you are almost there: fooobj = globals()['Foo']()  ...   fooobj.hello()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What I really need is a way to just instantiate the object.

That's what the `globals()['Foo']()` part does.

And it works for me:

```
>>> class Foo:
...   def __init__(self): print "Created a Foo!"
...
>>> globals()['Foo']()
Created a Foo!
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x02A33350>
>>>
```

Comment: What is the difference between f = globals()['Foo']() and f = ['Foo']()?  What does globals mean

Comment: @JPC, second is a syntax error. golbals() refer to the namespace of your module (which is a dictionary) and namespace is how Python deal with it's programs/modules. By golbals()['Foo'] you are accessing the key called 'Foo' in the glabals() dictionary.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.  Reflection in python is so much easier than in java!

Comment: `globals` is a function that returns a dict of the global variables. `globals()` calls that function, so now you have that dict. `globals()['Foo']` looks up the 'Foo' key in that dict, which gives you the value of the `Foo` global variable.

Comment: Coming back to this years later in response to a random upvote: `['Foo']()` isn't actually a syntax error, but it will cause a `TypeError` at runtime. It means "make a list with one element in it, the string `'Foo'`, call that list, and let `f` be a name for the result of the call". It fails because lists are not callable.