# Python getattr, howto address the constructor of a django model

Tags: python, django

In the code below I render the person model. Instead of person() I want to use a getattr to make use of a variable model name. Something like getattr('person', ????) 
The code below is a simplified verdion of my app engine code.

```
class person(djangoforms.ModelForm):

    name = djangoforms.forms.CharField(max_length=24, min_length=2, label = 'Name', required = True)


class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates', 'person.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {'form' : person(), 'name' : 'voscausa'}))
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for somtehing like that. I have already tried the '__init__'. It returns an error: ERROR    2011-03-24 14:45:26,290 __init__.py:395] 'method-wrapper' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of a python class is named `__init__`, so use `getattr(YourClass, '__init__')`.

However, this is probably not what you want. See [Does python have an equivalent to Java Class.forName()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname) - this might be the solution for your question.

Comment: I have tried to implement the second part of your answer. adding the the function you suggested : 
    def get_class( kls ):
        parts = kls.split('.')
        module = ".".join(parts[:-1])
        m = __import__( module )
        for comp in parts[1:]:
            m = getattr(m, comp)            
        return m
But this gives :
TypeError: 'ModelFormMetaclass' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
get_class('main.person')()
```

instead of

```
get_class('main.person')
```

to get

```
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {'form' : get_class('main.person')(), 'name' : 'voscausa'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    globals()[model_name]()
except KeyError:
    print "hey, you forgot to define %s"%model_name
```