# Django: Get generic view class from url name

Tags: django

What's the recommended way of getting a generic view class from the url name?

```
url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home')
```

So with 'home' I want to get the class HomeView.

Comment: You might want to go the other way round: from the view class' name to the url name. Why? Because class names are the more highly structured world. For instance, after a typo you will get a more meaningful error message if the offending line contains a name that does not resolve right there. (For class-based views, you would make a helper that applies `.as_view()` for you to make both the resolving and the notation simpler.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The get_class I got from the following question: [Does python have an equivalent to Java Class.forName()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname)

```
url = reverse('home')
resolver_match = resolve(url)
func = resolver_match.func
module = func.__module__
view_name = func.__name__

clss = get_class( '{0}.{1}'.format( module, view_name ) )
```

This is what I came up with myself I am very open to other answers.

Comment: I haven't found something better, but it's not completly satisfying because it is not exactly *fetching a view from its name*. The name is not enough to perform a call to `reverse` when  the said url needs extra parameters (id for instance).

Answer (score 11):

[Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) introduced 2 attributes to the functions that as_view() returns. `view_initkwargs` and `view_class`.

Combining this with Pickles' answer:

```
from django.urls import reverse, resolve

url = reverse('home')
view = resolve(url).func.view_class
```

Comment: @IceFire, I added imports to the example.

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by Pickels' answer:

```
import importlib 
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, resolve

view_name = 'my_view_name'

view_func = resolve(reverse(view_name)).func
module = importlib.import_module(view_func.__module__)
view = getattr(module, view_func.__name__)
```