# How to import a module in Python with importlib.import_module

Tags: python, import, module, python-importlib

I'm trying to use [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) in Python 2.7.2 and run into the strange error.

Consider the following dir structure:

```
    a
    |
    + - __init__.py
      - b
        |
        + - __init__.py
          - c.py
```

`a/b/__init__.py` has the following code:

```
    import importlib

    mod = importlib.import_module("c")
```

(In real code `"c"`has a name.)

Trying to `import a.b`, yields the following error:

```
    >>> import a.b
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "a/b/__init__.py", line 3, in 
        mod = importlib.import_module("c")
      File "/opt/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in   import_module
        __import__(name)
    ImportError: No module named c
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 142, accepted):

For relative imports you have to:

- a) use relative name
- b) provide anchor explicitly

  ```
  importlib.import_module('.c', 'a.b')
  ```

Of course, you could also just do absolute import instead:

```
importlib.import_module('a.b.c')
```

Comment: This works for python 3.x, too. (OP asked about 2.7.)

Comment: could I rename it like we do with `import long_name as ln` ?

Comment: you can, just assign a name to it like `abc = importlib.import_module('a.b.c')`

Comment: I am getting errors because I cannot find some utility functions that are not in a or b but are imported in c. How do I solve that?

Comment: what if `a` is already imported using `importlib` e.g `a = importlib.import_module("a")`, how can we then import b? `from a import b` does not work (`no module name 'a'`), if we don't want to import `a` again (which, for some reason, might have changed from the first import)

Answer (score 47):

I think it's better to use `importlib.import_module('.c', __name__)` since you don't need to know about `a` and `b`.

I'm also wondering that, if you have to use `importlib.import_module('a.b.c')`, why not just use `import a.b.c`?

Comment: It's useful when module name is a variable.

Comment: It's also useful when the module name is not a valid python identifier (e.g. has dashes in it).

Answer (score 26):

And don't forget to create a `__init__.py` with each folder/subfolder (even if they are empty)

Comment: Why though? I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for#448279 with the comment by @TwoBItAlchemist being most useful I think """Python searches a list of directories to resolve names in, e.g., import statements. Because these can be any directory, and arbitrary ones can be added by the end user, the developers have to worry about directories that happen to share a name with a valid Python module, such as 'string' in the docs example. To alleviate this, it ignores directories which do not contain a file named _ _ init _ _.py (no spaces), even if it is blank."""