# Keeping Python packages with the same top-level name in different directories

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-module, pythonpath

I have several Python packages that I'd like to keep on separate filesystems but which unfortunately share the same top-level module name.

To illustrate, the directory structure looks like this:

```
/fs1
  /top
    __init__.py
    /sub1
      __init__.py

/fs2
  /top
    __init__.py
    /sub2
      __init__.py
```

In Python 2.7, is there any way I can set up my `PYTHONPATH` so that I could import both `top.sub1` and `top.sub2` into the same script? Adding both `/fs1` and `/fs2` doesn't work, since it only allows one of the two submodules to be imported (whichever comes first on `PYTHONPATH`).

I could copy/symlink the two trees into one, but for practical reasons I'd rather not do that.

Comment: Yes, there is a way, and it's called "namespace packages". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python Note that if you do this, the `top` package has to be empty, that namespace can not contain anything except the sub1 and sub2 packages.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, one of which is `imp`:

```
import imp

foo = imp.load_source('module.name', '/path/to/file.py')
foo.MyClass()
```

([my source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path/67692#67692))

---

Another is with `importlib`

Relative:

```
importlib.import_module('.sub1', 'fs1.top')
```

Absolute:

```
importlib.import_module('fs1.top.sub1')
```

([my source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675054/how-to-import-a-module-in-python-with-importlib-import-module/10675081#10675081))