# Python importlib import_module Relative Import of Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-importlib

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675054/how-to-import-a-module-in-python-with-importlib-import-module), you can use `importlib` to `import_module` using a relative import like so:

```
importlib.import_module('.c', 'a.b')
```

Why doesn't relative import work for sklearn.feature_extraction.text ?

```
importlib.import_module('.text', 'sklearn.feature_extraction')
```

I verified that `text` is a module with:

```
from types import ModuleType
import sklearn.feature_extraction.text
isinstance(sklearn.feature_extraction.text, ModuleType)
```

Returns

```
True
```

**Edit**

By "doesn't work", I mean it doesn't import the module.

I am using Python 3.4

Absolute way works:

```
import importlib
text = importlib.import_module('sklearn.feature_extraction.text')
tfidf = text.TfidfVectorizer()
```

Relative way doesn't:

```
import importlib
text = importlib.import_module('.text', 'sklearn.feature_extraction')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    text = importlib.import_module('.text', 'sklearn.feature_extraction')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2249, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2199, in _sanity_check
SystemError: Parent module 'sklearn.feature_extraction' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 4):

The parent module needs to be imported before trying a relative import.

You will have to add `import sklearn.feature_extraction` before your call to import_module if you want it to work.

Nice explanation here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28154841/1951430

Comment: What then is the point and purpose of `importlib.import_module()` ? If I have to import `sklearn.feature_extraction` anyways, why wouldn't I just import `sklearn.feature_extraction.text` in the head of the file? Do you have a good use-case of when to use `importlib.import_module`?

Comment: importlib just provides the feature of the import statement in python code.

Comment: @Jarad you might not know the module name while writing the code. It can be read from some config file, for example.