# Python: import submodule from importlib module

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib

I have a directory like this:

```
parent.py ------+
    child1.py---+
    child2.py---+
    ... etc
```

I can import the parent module like this:

`importlib.import_module("parent"))`

So, what is the best way to get the child module now that I already have the parent module? I've tried `parent.child1`, `importlib.import_module("child1", parent)`, `parent.import_module('child1')`, etc. to no avail.

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate [how to import a module in python with importlib import-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675054/how-to-import-a-module-in-python-with-importlib-import-module)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to organize files in this way:

```
parent (directory)-+
    __init__.py ---+
    child1.py   ---+
    child2.py   ---+
```

In **init**.py you can import from child* files and that will be available to import from outside the module in parent.

Example `__init__.py`. It can also be empty, but it must exist.

```
from child1 import foo
from child2 import bar
```

Use from outside:

```
from parent import foo
or
from parent.child1 import foo
```

This doesn't answer directly your question. But, after you reorganize files in above way try to use importlib again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the optional parameter package for this:

```
importlib.import_module("child1", package="parent")
```

Documentation reference: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module