# Importing Python scripts iteratively from relative directories

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script called `test.py`, with the following code (I have simplified things significantly):

```
from foo import Bar

bar = Bar()
result = bar.do_something()
```

But I don't just have a single script called `foo`. I have many scripts called `foo`, organised in the following directory structure:

```
└── project
    ├── code
    │   ├── test.py
    └── scripts
        ├── script_1
            └── foo.py
        ├── script_2
            └── foo.py
        ├── script_3
            └── foo.py
        ├── script_4
            └── foo.py
        ├── script_5
            └── foo.py
```

Each `foo.py` has a slightly different implementation of something. And what I want to do with `test.py`, is to test all the scripts out, by importing each one and running some tests on it. Below is some code for this (*'s indicate pseudo-code)

```
*Get all script directories*
*For each directory in script directories:*
    *import foo.py from this directory*

    bar = Bar()
    result = bar.do_something()

    *Save the result for this directory*
```

How can I do this? In particular, how can I iteratively import scripts, e.g., 
 `*import foo.py from this directory*`?

Comment: You may need to create an __init__.py file under the project directory to specify which script you are using. Here are some detailed explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Comment: You must create dunder __init__.py file under the every project directory to access relativly to modules.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you change your scripts to create a package for them, as illustrated [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-access-python-package/). Then you can simply access each script individually as:

```py
import scripts.script_1.foo
```

or

```py
from scripts.script_1 import foo
```

**Iterative Importing:**

To iterate over the folders and import them, you may use "importlib" library of python. You will need to use "import_module" function from [this library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module). That being said, you still need to include __init__.py in every directory. An example of importing a module using this function is illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675054/how-to-import-a-module-in-python-with-importlib-import-module).

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this, but in your example, I would have to manually write down the names of the script directories (script_1, script_2, script_3 ...). Instead, I would like to be able to create a list of directories, then loop through them all and import "foo" on each loop. How can I do this? I tried create the list of directories as strings, but this did not work.

Comment: I see, then you need to use the importlib library of python to iterate over your folders. However, this library is intended for testing only. You can find information about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Comment: @Karnivaurus I added more information on how to achieve an iterative importing to my original answer. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a couple of different things, but the resulting code snippet looks like this:

```
import os, sys, importlib

# directory of your script folder
scripts_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"/../scripts/")


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(scripts_dir):
    # traverse the folder and find ones that has foo.py
    if 'foo.py' in files:
        sys.path.append(root)
        out = importlib.import_module('foo', package=root)

        # call the function in foo.py.  
        #In this case, I assumed there is a function called test 
        met = getattr(out, 'test')
        print(met())

        # clean up the path and imported modules
        sys.path.remove(root)
        del sys.modules['foo']
```