# Importing another .py file which starts with a number

Tags: python, import

I have to import another .py file with the name "00 xyz.py" how do I import the file as simply importing it the conventional way wouldn't work.

```
import 00 xyz.py as xyz
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a module in Python with importlib.import\_module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675054/how-to-import-a-module-in-python-with-importlib-import-module)

Comment: thanks @python_user, unfortunately I come from non tech background so still didn't get answer to my Q from that link.

Comment: `import importlib` `xyz = importlib.import_module('00 xyz')` this should work, make sure you type them in two lines

Comment: perfect! thanks @python_user that was most helpful!