# How to make Python imports dynamic?

Tags: python

Let's assume I import a custom python module as follows:
`from folder1.folder2 import module`

I use this import statement in multiple files. Can I add this file path in the environment variables so that I can use it in a dynamic way as follows or in a similar fashion:

```
(ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE)
EXPORT env_var_path=folder1.folder2

(PYTHON CODE)
from os.getenv("env_var_path") import module
```

The reason why I'm adding it in the env variables is that my folder names will change and keeping it in the env variables makes it a single source of change whenever I have to.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import arbitrary python source file. (Python 3.3+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009932/import-arbitrary-python-source-file-python-3-3) - another possible dupe using [importlib.import_module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675054/how-to-import-a-module-in-python-with-importlib-import-module)

Comment: You can just use the `PYTHONPATH` env var: directories first on it will be searched first by Python import mechanism.

Comment: @MikeScotty I can try that, but that doesn't look that elegant to me, is it?

Comment: @jsbueno The reason why I'm adding it in the env variables is that my folder names will change and keeping it in the env vars makes it a single source of change whenever I have to.

Comment: @PallavDoshi not sure what you mean by "doesn't look that elegant", it's literally the library to import modules in python, it's simply what must be used in this situation.