# Import python file of parameter values and options within a for loop

Tags: python

I have code that reads in parameter values and options from an external python file using `import optionsFile as my`, I then use these values in the rest of the code to calculate a result.

I now want to set up a series of these files and then loop through all of them in the main code.  I have placed the multiple files in a folder and am using `os.listdir(folderName)` to get a list of the file names.  However, I cannot figure out how to pull this into a for loop.  The MWE below shows the gist of what I want to achieve

MWE

```
list_of_files = ["temp1", "temp2"]
score = 0


import temp1 as my

myans = my.cat + my.dog
score = score + myans
print(score)

score = 0
for filename in list_of_files:
    import filename as my

    myans = my.cat + my.dog

    score = score + myans
    print(score)
```

I tried `my = importlib.import_module('temp1.py')` based on some suggestions that appeared relevant, but that gives ModuleNotFound as an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a module in Python with importlib.import\_module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675054/how-to-import-a-module-in-python-with-importlib-import-module)

Comment: Can you read the temp1.py file and extract the values instead of importing it as a module?

Comment: Try removing the .py: `my = importlib.import_module('temp1')`, then you can use it with the `filename` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `importlib` function takes arguments just like imports so the module name should not be followed by `.py`
Use it like:

```
my = importlib.import_module('temp1')
```

Then you can use it with the loop:

```
for filename in list_of_files:
    my = importlib.import_module(filename)
    myans = my.cat + my.dog

    score = score + myans
    print(score)
```