# How to have multiple models importing each other in Flask without causing circular imports?

Tags: python

Given the following Flask project structure, is it possible to import these models into each other without encountering a circular import error?

```
source
|-- __init__.py
|-- models
    |-- user.py
    |-- profile.py
    |-- posts.py
```

**source/models/user.py:**

```
from source.models.profile import Profile

class User(db.Model):
    ...

    profile = db.relationship(Profile.__name__, uselist=False, back_populates="user")
```

**source/models/profile.py**

```
from source.models.posts import Post
from source.models.user import User

class Profile(db.Model):
    ...

    user = db.relationship(User.__name__, back_populates="profile")

    posts = db.relationship(
        Post.__name__, uselist=False, back_populates="profile"
    )
```

**source/models/posts.py**

```
from source.models.profile.profile import Profile

class Post(db.Model):
    ...

    profile = db.relationship(Profile.__name__, back_populates="posts")
```

Example of error:

```
File "/app/source/models/posts.py" in <module> from source.models.profile import Profile
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Profile' from partially initialized module 
    'source.models.profile' (most likely due to a circular import) (/app/source/models/profile.py)
```

Comment: You can use the string name of the model instead

Comment: Try `importlib` (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675054/how-to-import-a-module-in-python-with-importlib-import-module)). Or import the module file like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336802/how-to-avoid-circular-imports-in-python)