# importlib: No module named

Tags: python, python-importlib

I have a folder `models` with a file `model.py`.
I want to import class `Model` from it and name it `NamedModel`.
If I do this using

```
NamedModel = importlib.import_module("models.model.Model")
```

I have the following error:

```
No module named models.model.Model
```

Although, if I use

```
from models.model import Model
```

it works. How do I use `importlib` to import this `Model`?

P.S. I can't use `from models.model import Model` because the name of the file and the name of the class are variables.

Comment: "P.S. I can't use from models.model import Model because the name of the file and the name of the class are variables."  Perhaps an alias then, `from modes.model import Model as NewModel`

Comment: @salparadise I can't use it as well. "models.model" is a string variable

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10675081/19593035)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import_module` only... well imports modules. You need to get a class from the module as it's attribute with [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
NamedModel = getattr(importlib.import_module("models.model"), 'Model')
```