# Dynamically instantiate object of the python class similar to PHP new $classname?

Tags: python, reflection

How to instantiated a class if its name is given as a string variable (i.e. dynamically instantiate object of the class). Or alternatively, how does the following PHP 5.3+ code

```
<?php

namespace Foo;

class Bar {};

$classname = 'Foo\Bar';
$bar = new $classname();
```

can be spelled in python?

**Also see**

[Does python have an equivalent to Java Class.forName()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code I use to go from a full class path (e.g. `foo.bar.baz.TheClass`) to the class itself:

```
def get_class(class_path):
    module_path, class_name = class_path.rsplit(".", 1)

    try:
        module = __import__(module_path, fromlist=[class_name])
    except ImportError:
        raise ValueError("Module '%s' could not be imported" % (module_path,))

    try:
        cls = getattr(module, class_name)
    except AttributeError:
        raise ValueError("Module '%s' has no class '%s'" % (module_path, class_name,))

    return cls
```

Usage:

```
>>> get_class('twisted.internet.nonexistant.Deferred')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    get_class('twisted.internet.nonexistant.Deferred')
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 7, in get_class
    raise ValueError("Module '%s' could not be imported" % (module_path,))
ValueError: Module 'twisted.internet.nonexistant' could not be imported
>>> get_class('twisted.internet.defer.NoClass')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    get_class('twisted.internet.defer.NoClass')
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 12, in get_class
    raise ValueError("Module '%s' has no class '%s'" % (module_path, class_name,))
ValueError: Module 'twisted.internet.defer' has no class 'NoClass'
>>> get_class('twisted.internet.defer.Deferred')
<class twisted.internet.defer.Deferred at 0x02B25DE0>
```

Note that this doesn't necessarily return a class, it just returns the attribute of the imported module:

```
>>> get_class('twisted.internet')
<module 'twisted.internet' from 'C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\__init__.pyc'>
```

Answer (score 1):

*foo.py*

```
class Bar(object):
    pass
```

*test.py*

```
from importlib import import_module

module = import_module('foo')
BarCls = getattr(module, 'Bar')
bar = BarCls()
```