# Using variable value as dictionary/class name in Python

Tags: python

My requirement is to use variable value for referncing class/dictionaries in Python. As a sample example, I have following data :-

```
class test1:
    pass

class test2:
   pass

test1_dict = {}
test2_dict = {}

testvariable = "test1"
```

Now I want to check value of `testvariable` and create an instance of class and append it in dictionary.

e.g.

```
if testvariable == "test1":
    test1inst = test1()
    test1_dict["test1"] = test1inst
elif testvariable == "test2":
    test2inst = test2()
    test2_dict["test2"] = test2inst
```

In the above code, I have to explicitly use `if/else` to check the value of `testvariable` and do the operations accordingly.

In my real scenario, I could have multiple values of `testvariable` and there could be multiple places where `if/else` check would be required. So, is it possible that somehow, I could be able to use the value of `testvariable` directly to refer dictionary/class instances without using `if/else`.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Got it, I need to use dict and its methods to manage data. Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is **almost never** a good reason to look up names like this. Python has a perfectly good data structure for mapping names to objects, and that is a dict. If you ever find yourself saying "I need a dynamic lookup of something", then a dict is the answer. In your case:

```
from collections import defaultdict
test_classes = {
    'test1': test1,
    'test2': test2
}
test_instances = defaultdict(list)
test_instances[testvariable].append(test_classes[testvariable])
```

Comment: I agree with you, but I am facing problems implementing the same in my actual code. Please see my edit, which represents my actual problem more closely.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Daniel Roseman that there is **almost never** a good reason to do this.  However, I'm up for a challenge!  The OP follows my lead at his or her own peril.

The secret is to use Python's exec function, which permits executing the contents of a string as Python code:

So,

```
if testvariable == "test1":
    test1inst = test1()
    test1_dict["test1"] = test1inst
elif testvariable == "test2":
    test2inst = test2()
    test2_dict["test2"] = test2inst
```

becomes

```
exec("%sinst = %s()" % (testvariable, testvariable))
exec("%s_dict[testvariable] = %sinst" % (testvariable, testvariable))
```

albeit with the caveat that other values of testvariable do nothing in the OP's case, and in the case using exec() result in NameError exceptions.

Comment: No, bad idea. You can do the same by looking up the class in the local variables or global variables: inst = locals()[testvariable]

Comment: Very true, although this method doesn't require testing for from where in the scope it comes.  Also, I think my answer made clear that it was a bad idea to do this. :)

Comment: Yeah, I just saw "exec" and went to a very dark place. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to combine some other posts and say that Python already has a dictionary that maps names of objects to the object. You can access local and global variables so as long as your class is defined in the module you can do:

```
my_inst[testvariable] = locals()[testvariable]()
```