# Creating instances of class based on string name of class

Tags: python

Is there a way to use a string (in my case read from a file) to find a class with the name matching the string, then create an instance of that class.  For example:

```
class FirstClass:
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.arg = arg1

values = ','.split('FirstClass', 'argument')
# need the magic for this:
values[0](*values[1:])
```

But of course using `values[0]` doesn't work there, because it's a string, not a class.  Is there a way to automatically convert the string to the class there?  Especially if I have many classes and cannot know in advance which one to instantiate, like reading the values from a CSV and wanting the right class to handle a line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access a variable by name using `locals()` or `globals()` respectively. In your case this would work as such:

```
locals()[values[0]](*values[1:])
```

Comment: You probably want `globals()` though so that it works within a function scope. Also see this answer for if the class is part of another module you want to dynamically load http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname