# How can use variable class name and function in Python

Tags: python, django

I have this class

```
class Test(object):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
          pass

       def make(self):
          pass
```

Now i have class name and function name as variables like

```
class_name = "Test"
func_name = "make"
```

i want to call `Test(**kwargs).make()`

I tried this

```
    cls_name  = "Test"
    callback  = getattr(cls_name, "make")
    obj = callback()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your class is at global level, you can access it through `globals()`.  (Other possible options are `locals()` or `vars()`.)  For example:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         print("in test init")
...     def make(self):
...         print("in test make")
... 
>>> cls_name = "Test"
>>> method_name = "make"
>>> callback = getattr(globals()[cls_name](), method_name)
in test init
>>> callback()
in test make
```

If your `Test` class were in a different module, you could use `getattr(module_containing_test, cls_name)` instead of the `globals()` lookup.

Comment: what bout if make is also variable

Comment: @user3214546 -- updated for variable attribute access.

Comment: what if i don't have that in globals but in cls_name ,what if i actually pass the class itsself rather the string , then what do i need to do

Comment: so then it will be like   `getattr(getattr(module_containing_test, cls_name), method_name)()`

Comment: @user3214546 -- If you have the class itself, you probably want to instantiate it, and then you can get a method.  If you only need one method per instantiation, then `callback = getattr(my_class(), method_name)` should work.

Comment: @user3214546 -- close.  In order to call a regular method (not a class method or static method) you need an instantiated class:  `getattr(getattr(module_containing_test, cls_name)(), method_name)()`

Answer (score 0):

The below piece of code seems working and I don't know if its safe, as most developers hate `eval`.

```
class Test(object):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          print "I'm init"
      def make(self):
          print "I'm make"

class_name = "Test"
func_name = "make"
a = eval(class_name+"()")
eval('a'+"."+func_name+"()")
```

Comment: It's not particularly unsafe in this context, because you are not passing it random data, but it's not particularly efficient in this context, either.

Answer (score 0):

Some compilation of answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python)

```
# You have to prepend module name to class name

class_name = "moduletest.Test"
func_name = "make"

def get_class( kls ):
    parts = kls.split('.')
    module = ".".join(parts[:-1])
    m = __import__( module )
    for comp in parts[1:]:
        m = getattr(m, comp)
    return m

# You're creating object here, so have to pass all needed argument then
test = get_class(class_name)() 
callback = getattr(test, func_name)
obj = callback()
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for class in [globals()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=globals#globals) and then invoke method via [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=getattr#getattr).

```
clazz = globals()["Test"]
obj = clazz()
getattr(obj, "make")()
```