# Import error trying to import a module that has class methods with typed parameters

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I'm trying to import a module (`module_name.py`) that I've created [using `__import__()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname)
but am seeing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 80, in <module>
    testImportMethod()
  File "test.py", line 68, in testImportMethod
    m = __import__("module_name")
  File "/dir/module_name.py", line 147
    def insert_model(model: MyModel):
                          ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`module_name.py` has the following code:

```
class MyModel(object):
    property1 = None
    property2 = None

class ThingDAO(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_thing_by_id(id):
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def insert_model(model: MyModel):
    ...
```

Why does the import process have a problem with typed parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the import process that has problems with typed parameters. The problem is that typed parameters were added in Python 3.5 ([PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484)) and raise such SyntaxErrors for example on Python 2.7.

Likely (given the `SyntaxError`) you're using an older version of Python and to make it work you either have to install and use a newer Python version or use on of the [workarounds mentioned in the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code), for example:

```
class MyModel(object):
    property1 = None
    property2 = None

class ThingDAO(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_thing_by_id(id):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def insert_model(model):
        # type: (MyModel) -> None
        pass
```