# Getting type such as typing.List[Something] from string representation "typing.List[Something]"

Tags: python

Given the following code:

```
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Paradise:
    saints : List[str]

the_type_i_want = Paradise.__dataclass_fields__["saints"].type
```

`the_type_i_want` has a string representation `"typing.List[str]"`

Looking to the content of the type `the_type_i_want.__dict__`

we get:

```
 {'_inst': False,
 '_special': False,
 '_name': 'List',
 '__origin__': list,
 '__args__': (str,),
 '__parameters__': (),
 '__slots__': None
 }
```

Now, given again a string representation such as : `"typing.List[str]"` or also something more complicated such as `"typing.List[MyClass]"` or even something worse such as `typing.Optional[typing.Map[str,MyOtherClass]]]`.

I would like to know if it is possible to recreate the corresponding type whose representation would be the type I specify.

Is is possible in Python **without** type erasure? (you see somewhere the lower kind type keep `str` is kept in the `__dict__`)

So after all what I would need is a quite generic method that receives a string name and returns a type:

```
def class_for_name(class_name: str) -> type:
    ???
```

Here is something similar:

[Does python have an equivalent to Java Class.forName()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname)

but it is too raw as it is not able to accomodate generics.

Comment: It'd make more sense to use `dataclasses.fields` and `typing.get_type_hints`. `dataclasses.fields` will give you field info without poking undocumented implementation details, and `typing.get_type_hints` resolves string annotations, which you can then match against the fields.

Comment: Please add an example of what recreating the corresponding specified type would look like or how you would like it to work or be done.